# jQuery .change() only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a DropDownList called "ddlCaseFiles".
I then have a script which I import that contains the jQuery .change() function to capture the event. Then I have 3 radio buttons which sorts the dropDownList. When the default radio button is loaded, then the event fires. But as soon as I select another radio button, then the event doesn't fire anymore.

Here is my DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFiles" DataSourceID="dsMyCaseFiles" 
DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" />
```

and here is my jQuery .change():

```
 $('#ddlCaseFiles').change(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#lblNextExhibitNumber').text('');
    var temp = $(this).val();
});
```

Here is a snipper of what the radio buttons do:

```
    protected void rbByFileName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFilesReverse";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
}

protected void rbByFileID_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFiles";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
}
```

I have never used the .change() before. So maybe I am missing something

Comment: try the onclick (or click) event.

Comment: that doesn't capture anything since it fire even if i just click on the dropdownlist. I am trying to capture the selectedValue. but via jquery

Comment: Is this not because you have the Dropdownlist as runat="server" which would do a postback?

Comment: This will cause an error because I need to assign data field and values to the dropdownlist

Comment: i think you use this with your dropdownlist ClientIDMode="Static" i think this will help you

Comment: Is this all in an update panel?

Comment: the ddl is in an update panel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your CheckedChanged events of the radio buttons don't trigger the dropdown change event. The JS change event fires when the selected value of a drop down changes. This doesn't necessarily happen when you change the `DataSourceID`, does it?

I'm not sure how to trigger this in ASP. Perhaps `ddlCaseFiles.SelectedIndexChanged()`?

Otherwise, you could add a click event handler to the radios:

```
$('input[type="radio"].someCssClass').click(function(){
   $('#ddlCaseFiles').trigger('change');
});
```

**EDIT:**

This is just a guess, but it looks like the `CheckedChanged` might be modifying the `<select>` element on the page. For example, is it reinserted every time `DataSourceID` changes?

Try changing your dropdown change event handler like this using the `.on()` function:

```
$('body').on('change', '#ddlCaseFiles', function () {
    debugger;
    $('#lblNextExhibitNumber').text('');
    var temp = $(this).val();
});
```

Note: for better performance change `$('body')` to some container closer to the dropdown.

The `.change()` function attaches the `change` handler to an element on a page. If ASP removes an element and re-adds it later then the handler is gone.

A handler attached using the `.on()` function persists even if the element is removed. [Read more here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: but isn't the JS event suppose to fire every time I change my selection? The radio buttons only change the sorting of the fileID's. I still have to select one from the list

Comment: Ah, right. Are you able to post the JS generated by ASP for the radio change event handlers? It looks like ASP is messing about with the drop down.

Comment: I will take a look and post it in the main question

Comment: It seems your "EDIT:" code does the trick and catches the values even after the radio buttons have been selected. Now to figure out why >.> I will post the Js Code generated

Comment: thank you so much for this information. This goes more in depth than I thought

Answer (score 0):

A more modern answer using jquery 3.6

```
    $(document).on('change', "#ddlCaseFiles", function (e) {
      debugger;
      $('#lblNextExhibitNumber').text('');
      var temp = $(this).val();
    });
```