# jQuery change event fired only once - editableTableWidget and autoNumeric plugins

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm using two plugins: [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) and [editableTableWidget](http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/).
The first to format currency and second to let user edit table.
I need to combine them so when the user edit the table, the currency is auto formatted.

The problem is that the change event is fired only once for each cell with ID import, if I try to edit more than once time the currency is not formatted

That's my HTML

```
<table id="preview">
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td id="date"></td>
   <td id="description"></td>
   <td id="import"></td>
   <th id="total"></th> --> NOT EDITABLE
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="date"></td>
   <td id="description"></td>
   <td id="import"></td>
   <th id="total"></th> --> NOT EDITABLE
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="date"></td>
   <td id="description"></td>
   <td id="import"></td>
   <th id="total"></th> --> NOT EDITABLE
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

That's my jQuery

```
$('#preview').editableTableWidget().tableFormat().find('tbody').focus();
$.fn.tableFormat = function () {        
    'use strict';
    var element = $(this)
    element.find('td').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is("#import")) {
            $(this).autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ','});
            return;
        } 
    })
    return this;
};
```

I read also these posts:

- [jQuery .change() event is only fired once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143662/jquery-change-event-is-only-fired-once)
- [jQuery .change() only fires once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178252/jquery-change-only-fires-once)

Comment: Use classes for sets of objects as selectors, not id's. Responding only on first id is expected behavior. Use classes...

Comment: no way also with classes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it work.
Before initialize autoNumeric with "init" and then "update" like this:

```
$('#preview').editableTableWidget().tableFormat().find('tbody').focus();
$.fn.tableFormat = function () {        
    'use strict';
    var element = $(this)
    element.find('td').on('change', function () {
    $(this).autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ','});
    if ($(this).is("#import")) {
            $(this).autoNumeric('update', {aSep: '.', aDec: ','});
            return;
        } 
    })
    return this;
};
```